# Threads Interrupt not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I am just looking into threads and interrupts. I got a small working example. Unfortunately i don't
see the ineterrupt is working. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code :-

```
public class SleeperTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Runnable sleeper = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                // try{
                // System.out.println("Sleeper is going to sleep");
                // Thread.sleep(2000);
                // System.out.println("Sleeper is awake");
                // }
                // catch(InterruptedException e){
                // System.out.println("Sleeper got interrupted");
                // }
                // System.out.println("Hello Ben");
                if(Thread.interrupted()){
                System.out.println("Thread has been interrupted");
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                }

            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(sleeper);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

It's not going to the interrupted block. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i don't see a race condition here. I am just unable to understand the concept why ineterrupt is not working?

Comment: It's almost certainly a race condition. Your `sleeper` thread is likely immediately checking if it's interrupted, seeing that it isn't, and then exiting, especially since your first thread is sleeping for half a second, which is way more time than necessary for the other thread to get scheduled and execute.

Comment: By the time your main thread gets to execute `t.interrupt()`, your `sleeper` thread has already finished executing!

Comment: I am not very well versed with threads, if someone can tell me how interrupt can work in this? I don't want any method that can throw interrupted exception. I want it to work without it.

Comment: @benz Simply stated remove `Thread.sleep(500);`

Comment: Why don't you try putting some code in the run block that will run for a while such as a loop with a million iterations

Comment: @m3th0dman Still possible to get a race condition, because then the race would be whether the interrupt would happen before the `if` statement

Comment: @user3580294 You're right, although it won't reproduce as often as the presented code.

Comment: @m3th0dman That does not remove the race condition. He might see two different behaviors, then, depending on timing of the threads' executions.

Comment: @Santa can you please explain your comment?

Comment: Basically, you'll have a race between the thread you spawned trying to check whether it has been interrupted and the original thread trying to interrupt the spawned thread.

Comment: @user3580294 thankyou so much. i have understood your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to annotate a possible execution flow for both threads in `(number)`.

**Main Thread:**

```
        Thread t = new Thread(sleeper);
        t.start();                           <<< (1) your thread is started; its execution now runs in parallel to this thread
        Thread.sleep(500);                   <<< (2) this thread is now sleeping; the "sleeper" thread is still running!
        t.interrupt();                       <<< (3) 500 milliseconds (0.5 second) later, trying to interrupt, but that thread is most likely already finished by now; this is a no-op
```

---

**sleeper Thread:**

```
        public void run() {                   <<< (1) this thread starting 
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {       <<< (2.1) Am I interrupted? (Not yet, so no)
                 System.out.println("Thread has been interrupted");
                 System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                                              <<< (2.2) Finished executing. This thread is done.
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks a ton for your explanation. I get your point and understand your explanation perfectly. I am unable to understand the race condition in this example.

Comment: @benz I suppose in this case the "race" is between the spawned thread trying to see whether it has been interrupted and the original thread trying to interrupt the spawned thread after sleeping. In this case, the spawned thread always wins due to the sleep, but it technically still a race condition.

Comment: @user3580294 thanks so much. I completely got your explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition. The created thread executes and passes the `if` block before the main thread can interrupt it.

An interrupt is usually meant to be used to stop (or notify) a long running thread that runs in a loop. Try something like

```
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    System.out.println("not interrupted");
}
System.out.println("interrupted");
// then exits
```